# include Pandas plot in MatplotlibWidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, pandas

I have a Pandas plot that looks like this:

```
ts = pd.Series(randn(1000), index=date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

And I would like to show it in a GUI, which I designed with Qt Designer. As I am using Python(x,y), there is a MatplotlibWidget, which I placed on my Gui. However, I am not sure how to make this widget display my earlier created plot, or if this is possible at all...? I am able to make the widget display basic plots like:

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
self.widget.axes.plot(x, x**2)
self.widget.draw()
```

Is there any way to make the widget display my Pandas plot, or do I have to create a new class? How would I go about this? As I am using Qt Designer, could I add this new plot class as a widget? How?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I never used Qt, but i guess you can do it using the ax argument on ts.plot(ax=<widget_axes>). Probably <widget_axes> = self.widget.axes.

Comment: Hi lodagro! I can acutally plot the last column in the dataframe when I do this: ts.plot(ax=self.widget.axis). However it puts the full legend into the plot (which I want), but it omits the other columns - any idea on how to fix that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the example code above, ts is not a Frame but a Series. I`m assuming you are now trying to plot a DataFrame, it should work the same. If some columns are not plotted it is either because they don`t hold numerical data or plot(columns=...) is used to select which columns to plot.